# Cannot fix Firebase 11.2.0

Tags: android, firebase

Above 11 versions work such for authentication, database, etc. But when we are going to compile 11.2.0 version, I can see this error:

> (30, 13) Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase.firebase-auth:11.2.0

Comment: Please see this link, https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android, Did not find 11.2.0, it is 11.0.4. Please change and see the result

Comment: @AndroidAddict That's not true, 11.2.0 is available via maven.google.com.

Comment: I had the same issue, after changing it to 11.0.4 I could fix the issue and it happened for me today only.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add google maven repository to your project build.gradle (not app module). Currently, there is no information for this in [Firebase Android Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```